# Determine if fragment is pushed or popped in onBackStackChanged()

Tags: android, android-fragments

Say I've pushed three fragments onto the stack: Fragment A, B, and C.

**Goal**: When I press back on Fragment C I want to have some hook into determining if Fragment B is showing and call frag.onShow().

**Thought process**: I added an onBackStackChangedListener in order to determine when fragments were added or removed from the stack. Here I check whether the current fragment is equal to the new one (pushed) or different (popped).

**Problem**: Both frag and getCurrentFragment() are returning the current fragment AFTER Fragment C has been dismissed. So here the new fragment is Fragment B but getCurrentFragment() is also returning Fragment B so it doesn't think it's a pop.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new OnBackStackChangedListener() {

  @Override
  public void onBackStackChanged() {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    int count = fm.getBackStackEntryCount();
    if (count > 0) {
      String name = fm.getBackStackEntryAt(count - 1).getName();
      MyFragment frag = (MyFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(name);
      MyFragment currFrag = getCurrentFragment();
      if (frag != currFrag) {
        if (frag != null) {
          frag.onShow();
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

public MyFragment getCurrentFragment() {
  Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_holder);
  if (fragment instanceof MyFragment) {
    return (MyFragment) fragment;
  }
  return null;
}
```

**Question**: Is there a way to get the last popped fragment? Or is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do? I can always keep some variable around to determine if I'm popping or pushing but I was hoping for a less hacky feeling way.

Thanks.

Comment: What the hell ... Why not just call your onShow() method in fragment B onResume() ?

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're trying to do.  You would never want to call the lifecycle methods of a Fragment (onResume, onStart).  Additionally, if Fragment B must know when it's visible, it can rely on `onStart()` being called whenever it's being re-shown from the backstack.  You do not have to do this yourself.

Comment: @DeeV you're right that I shouldn't be calling those myself. I just got a little desperate while debugging. And no, onResume() and onStart() do not get called when the fragment is shown off the backstack. They are tied to the same activity and these lifecycle methods are tightly coupled with their containing activities. This is why I was making my onShow() method to begin with

Comment: @rakoonise  Apologies.  They don't get called if you don't remove them during the transaction.  If you're just stacking Fragments on top of each other, then they are technically all still "visible" and active as far as the FragmentManager is concerned.  Assuming that your fragments are only visible at one time, you can call `FragmentTransaction#hide(fragment)` to hide a Fragment.  `Fragment#onHiddenChanged()` will be called both when you hide it and when you unhide it.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @DeeV for helping me understand fragment visibility.

> If you're just stacking Fragments on top of each other, then they are technically all still "visible" and active as far as the FragmentManager is concerned. Assuming that your fragments are only visible at one time, you can call FragmentTransaction#hide(fragment) to hide a Fragment. Fragment#onHiddenChanged() will be called both when you hide it and when you unhide it.

I'll be transferring my code to what they suggested. I also realized that if you do need to do it manually like I was doing earlier, a variable of the last fragment count will help determine whether it was a push or a pop.